# MS access 2016 "Could not use File (Name), file already in use" Error in home internet

Tags: ms-access

We have MS access applications placed in domain shared network path.
Application is working fine when connected to network. If connected to personal internet it is throwing  "Could not use File (Name), file already in use" Error. I'm not facing this error when connected to Office network.